# Setting background color to row in Reporting Services table does not affect all cells

Tags: reportingservices-2005, background-color, tablerow

I have a Reporting Services 2005 report that has a tablerow with a background color conditionally set. The individual cells do not have that property being set.  When I run the report,  one of the columns in the resulting table does not have any background color.  The other cells in that row do.  I am noticing that the markup results in the table cells themselves being set and not the row.  The table cell(s) in question do not have background color set via html.

FYI, the column in question does have its action set.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran across this problem and basically here's what was happening... When you set the background for a row, internally the background for each column is set.  If you add a column (or change a column) after setting the row background, the background for the column is reset... so even if the row background is still set, that column will be cleared... You'll need to go back in and set the column's background (or just remove the row's background and then reset the row's background) to set all the columns on the row.

Comment: Tried that - no luck.  I remove all background color setting, deploy, all blank (expected).  Go back and add background color setting to row, deploy, back to original problem...